# I can just view my website locally through IP on mobile but buttons are not working like saving data etc

Tags: xampp, local, mobile-website

[view page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kMhTN.jpg)

My client want to use a website on Android mobile but he doesn't want online. He just wants to access it within a network, but my problem is that some buttons are not working like the save button used for to save data, and the reset button to reset all fields.

I am using codeignator with xampp

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the browser console when those buttons are pressed? You should take a look on a device that has a console you can monitor to see if you are getting errors in your JavaScript. If you do see any and still need help, please add those errors to the question.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can run your program on your browser by internal IP to debug.

You can use the inspector of browser to check console if any error like javascript or php things happen when you click submit or reset